# Is it wise (safe) to connect a Bench Power Supply to a UPS?

Tags: ups

The power at my place is generally reliable but a few times a year we have an outage or brownout.  With my luck, it will happen just when I am testing something on the bench (microelectronics).  I am not so concerned about losing power completely.  Rather, my concern is if there is an intermittent power hiccup that causes a surge/overshoot when the power comes right back on.

Since my UPS provides power to connected devices with a battery, I'm thinking it should keep the Bench Power Supply going without skipping a beat.  Are there any gotchas?

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Comment: Wasn't sure if the power waveform coming from the UPS battery would be different from the profile of the AC directly, and if any difference would confuse the power supply.  Maybe I was overthinking this.

Comment: I think your concern is reasonable, but it should be OK to hook it up as long as the UPS is of reasonable quality.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special about a bench power supply. If the UPS can keep your computer, which has a power supply that is similar to your bench supply, running through glitches and outages, then it will also power the bench power supply and whatever circuit you have powered from it.